# Matchs aleatorios de 100 jugadores

Tags: java

estoy intentando crear un método que dados 100 números enteros (cada número representa a un jugador) le genere a cada uno 5 matchs aleatorios con otros de los 100 números. Y luego  que se apilen todas estas posibilidades en un Set. Estos matchs deben contarse de manera bilateral. Es decir que si el número 1 matchea con el 35 entonces el 35 también hizo match con el 1 y no es válido que en el Set final haya un match 1 y 5 y a la vez otro 5 y 1, ya que se entiende que el orden de los numeros no importa y no pueden haber matchs repetidos.

Había pensado que la salida fuese un Set<List> donde cada List tiene el mismo tamaño de 2 ya que representa a un match.

Mi problema es que cada vez que intento crear algo me resulta un algoritmo inestable o un loop infinito, y no entiendo bien en que estoy fallando.

He estado investigando y he visto que en general cuando se habla de matcheos se hace referencia a matchs que tienen condiciones de preferencia. En mi caso no hay tal condición, no hay preferencia de ningún jugador por otro. Busco que sea lo mas aleatorio posible.

Este es uno de los tantos intentos fallidos, al probarlo en general no arroja resultado, probablemente porque se trate de alguna especie de loop infinito.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Matching {
    
    private int p2;
    private int p1;
    /**
     * 
     * @param n: the number of players
     * @param rounds: games per player
     * @return 
     */
    public Set<List<Integer>> create(int n, int rounds){
        final Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>(n * rounds);
        final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            map.put(i, new HashSet<>(5));
        }
        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            p1 = i;
            while (map.get(i).size() < 5) {
                p2 = r.nextInt(n);
                if (p2 != i && map.get(p2).size() < 5) {
                    map.merge(i, new HashSet<>(), (x1, x2) -> {
                        x1.add(p2);
                        x1.addAll(x2);
                        return x1;
                    });
                    map.merge(p2, new HashSet<>(), (x1, x2) -> {
                        x1.add(p1);
                        x1.addAll(x2);
                        return x1;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        map.keySet().stream().forEach(integer -> {
            Set<Integer> m = map.get(integer);
            List<Integer> mList = m.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
            for(Integer match : mList) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(integer, match));
                if(!set.contains(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(match,integer))))
                    set.add(list);
            }
        });
        return set;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Esto ... ¿ No sería mucho mas fácil simplemente desordenar el conjunto de los 100, y luego ir sacando de 5 en 5 ? ¿ O es que tiene que ser de esa forma tan tan tan complicada por algún motivo exótico que no soy capaz de imaginar ?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Trauma, es más facil hacer un Set<Integer> de tamaño 100 e ir insertando números de forma aleatoria o desrodenada y posterior irlos sacando del Set para construir los match

Comment: Sí, tienen razón, es mas límitado como lo proponen, pero mucho mas sencillo y cumple el objetivo. Gracias!!